# Retrieving common column data from two tables in a single column with out duplicates in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

Below are the 2 tables from which i want to retrieve common column ie "location" from two tables in to a single column with out duplicates... I am using this query..

```
SELECT datan1.location,
       temp.location
FROM datan1
LEFT OUTER JOIN TEMP ON datan1.location=temp.location
UNION
SELECT datan1.location,
       temp.location
FROM datan1
RIGHT OUTER JOIN TEMP ON datan1.location=temp.location;
```

but i am not getting what i expected... any help is highly appreciated

Expected Output

Location
 1.Mysore
  2.Hyderabad 3. Chennai

Hyderabad should not come as it is repeated

[image: TAble Data]

Comment: UNION with DISTINCT …? Why do you have data of the same structure in different tables to begin with?

Comment: *i am not getting what i expected* - What is it that you expect?

Comment: I am expecting to reterive location column of two tables with out duplicate values

Comment: I am expecting better quality questions. See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0):

if you want common locations between the two tables  you should use  inner  join

```
select location
from datan1
inner join temp on temp.location = datan1.location
```

if you want all the location in both the table  you could use a simply union  avoinding left and right join

```
select location
from datan1
union 
select location
from temp
```